# Does Twilio two-factor authentication supports call to specific extensions

Tags: authentication, twilio, twilio-api, two-factor-authentication, twilio-click-to-call

I have a query that does Twilio Two Factor authentication call supports calling extensions. Like If I am a user and I requested twilio to authenticate me on call but I am using landline number and my landline number contains extension. How twilio will work in that case? How can I register my extension?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that 2FA via voice does not support calling to extensions, just to the number itself.

I would recommend that users don't, if they can, use landline numbers to receive 2FA codes as that means their ability to log on to a site protected with 2FA is locked to that location only.